# PHP replace dash with 0 from array when inserting to mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm inserting/updating a mysql table from json URL, but some of the values in $points contain a dash and I want to amend to a zero (or null would be fine) when updating so that I can have the column set to INT.

I know how to simply replace all - to 0 in mysql but stuck when it comes to trying to do as part of update from a json URL. My code is:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) { 
$sus = $array['formguide'][$i]['SUSPENSION'];
$wpoints = $array['formguide'][$i]['WEEKPOINTS'];
$tcode = $array['formguide'][$i]['TEAMCODE'];
$val = $array['formguide'][$i]['VALUE'];
$points = $array['formguide'][$i]['POINTS'];
$pname = $array['formguide'][$i]['PLAYERNAME'];
$tname = $array['formguide'][$i]['TEAMNAME'];
$sixwpoints = $array['formguide'][$i]['SIXWEEKPOINTS'];
$injury = $array['formguide'][$i]['INJURY'];
$playerid = $array['formguide'][$i]['PLAYERID'];
$pos = $array['formguide'][$i]['POS'];

//insert or update values into mysql
$sql = "INSERT INTO formguide (suspension, weekpoints, teamcode, 
                      value, points, playername, teamname, 
                      sixweekpoints, injury, playerid, pos)
        VALUES ('$sus', '$wpoints', '$tcode','$val','$points','$pname','$tname',
           '$sixwpoints','$injury','$playerid','$pos')
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE suspension='$sus', weekpoints='$wpoints', 
            teamcode='$tcode', value='$val', points='$points', playername='$pname', 
            teamname='$tname', sixweekpoints='$sixwpoints', injury='$injury', 
            playerid='$playerid', pos='$pos'";
```

I tried REPLACE() on points within the UPDATE() section i.e.:

```
...points=REPLACE('$points','-','0'), playername='$pname', ...
```

however that didn't work.

Any ideas how I can do this, or is there an alternative to have the points column as INT and accept a dash?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`REPLACE` is for modifying values coming from SQL, whereas you want to modify a value coming from PHP.

Use `str_replace` instead.

```
$points = str_replace('-', '0', $points);
```

Comment: Perfect! that worked. Thanks.

I tried to do the same but for an empty string but it doesn't update. The json returns as follows "SIXWEEKPOINTS": null,
Any ideas? I tried a few suggestions on other posts but no joy.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. This wouldn't work on an empty string, as the `-` wouldn't exist to be replaced. Can you update your question with an example?

Comment: i've amended $sixwpoints from the original in my question to
`$sixwpoints = str_replace('','0',$array['formguide'][$i]['SIXWEEKPOINTS']);` 
however, in mysql i don't get a zero i still see a blank

Comment: What's the value of `$array['formguide'][$i]['SIXWEEKPOINTS']`?

Comment: It's either an integer or null. This is example from the json:
`{
"SUSPENSION": null,
"WEEKPOINTS": 0,
"TEAMCODE": "HUD",
"VALUE": "2.4",
"POINTS": "6",
"PLAYERNAME": "Hefele, M",
"TEAMNAME": "Huddersfield Town",
"SIXWEEKPOINTS": "2",
"INJURY": "Achilles injury",
"PLAYERID": "2241",
"POS": "DEF"
},
{
"SUSPENSION": null,
"WEEKPOINTS": 0,
"TEAMCODE": "SWA",
"VALUE": "2.5",
"POINTS": "6",
"PLAYERNAME": "Rangel, A",
"TEAMNAME": "Swansea City",
"SIXWEEKPOINTS": null,
"INJURY": "Groin Injury",
"PLAYERID": "2128",
"POS": "DEF"
},`

Comment: Okay. So neither value is an empty string, so nothing will match to be replaced with `0`. See https://3v4l.org/Pp3Do. You more likely want to use `$sixwpoints = $sixwpoints ?? 0;`, which will return the non null value or `0`.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.
Thanks for helping out @fubar

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to escape or cast all values to avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities. Since you did not post your table schema, I'm guessing the types. `mysqli_real_escape_string()` is for strings, `(int)` and `(float)` for numbers of the respective type.

Doing that, your original problem is solved automatically, as PHP returns `0`, if you cast '-' to integer.

Second, your query is a usecase for a *proper* use of `REPLACE`, which works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
{ 
    $sus        = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $array['formguide'][$i]['SUSPENSION']);
    $wpoints    = (int) $array['formguide'][$i]['WEEKPOINTS'];
    $tcode      = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $array['formguide'][$i]['TEAMCODE']);
    $val        = (float) $array['formguide'][$i]['VALUE'];
    $points     = (int) $array['formguide'][$i]['POINTS'];
    $pname      = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $array['formguide'][$i]['PLAYERNAME']);
    $tname      = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $array['formguide'][$i]['TEAMNAME']);
    $sixwpoints = (int) $array['formguide'][$i]['SIXWEEKPOINTS'];
    $injury     = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $array['formguide'][$i]['INJURY']);
    $playerid   = (int) $array['formguide'][$i]['PLAYERID'];
    $pos        = (int) $array['formguide'][$i]['POS'];

    // Insert or update values into mysql
    $sql = "REPLACE INTO formguide SET
                suspension='$sus',
                weekpoints=$wpoints,
                teamcode='$tcode',
                value=$val,
                points=$points,
                playername='$pname',
                teamname='$tname',
                sixweekpoints=$sixwpoints,
                injury='$injury',
                playerid=$playerid,
                pos=$pos
    ";  

    // ...
}
```